# Swift HTTP POST Request Login

Tags: html, ios, swift, post

Hey I'm trying to figure out this problem for quite some time so now I'm asking you guys for help.
In my Project I'm trying to send a POST request to a website with a login form to access the server.But I somehow don't manage to pass the data.
The website I'm trying to access is [https://edu.sh.ch](http://edu.sh.ch)

in the Inspector of my browser I can see it needs a Post method to pass the data :

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/uniquesigfe5a0f1f915f15b647d0b7a5306be984/uniquesig0/InternalSite/Validate.asp" onsubmit="return(SubmitForm());"></form>
```

here's my code:

func PostingCredentials(){

```
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: self.manipulatedUrl)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

        // Compose a query string
        let form1 = "user_name=MyUsername&password=MyPassword"

        request.HTTPBody = form1.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            println("response = \(response)")
            // You can print out response object
            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            //
            println("responseString = \(responseString)")

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

Note that **self.manipulateUrl** equals to the url which shows up when I log in normally and submit my credentials (https://edu.sh.ch/uniquesigfe5a0f1f915f15b647d0b7a5306be984/uniquesig0/InternalSite/Validate.asp)

The Post Function posts something but the response is always some sort of error page( I'm not getting any error in the code but the response of the server is an error)

So for the end my main question are :

- whats the problem with my code
- where do I have to send my POST method to,to the login page url or the validation url?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you not pass language parameter in ios?

Comment: Did you reproduce the POST request using cURL or some HTTP requesting tool ?

Comment: @Fantattitude What do you mean with reproduce the POST request? Do you mean how I found out that I need to use POST? sorry im new to programming with http

Comment: @user4321563 You will have a hard time requesting something from a server if you don't understand well how the server or HTTP works, what I meant was that if you want to reproduce the request your browser would make when using the form you could take a look at your browser inspector to understand what is requested in the HTTP request (headers + content).

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. The website ask for cookies so my next question is how can I save them?

Comment: Cookies come in the HTTPResponse headers.  Just read the cookie out of the header.   http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265

Answer (score 2):

Some Problem with your webpage. Something is wrong in web coding. Then also you can try below code :

```
let form1 = "user_name=MyUsername&password=MyPassword"
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://edu.sh.ch")!)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
request.HTTPBody = form1.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    //var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. In your request your using NSJSONSerialization but why if theres no JSON in the website?